# MongoDB connection timeout on Android

Tags: java, android, mongodb, mongodb-java, mlab

I made a little app with Java Swing and MongoDB.

I'm trying to develop the same app for Android and the connection to the MongoDB database does a connection timeout when I try to connect.

I tried the app with my Samsung with 3G access and my android virtual device which had access to internet.

I use a MongoLab database, the same code as my Java Swing app and the same driver.

```
//DB
MongoClientURI uri  = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://user:password@ds033750.mongolab.com:33750/db"); 
MongoClient mongo = null;
try {
    mongo = new MongoClient(uri);
} 
catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
DB db = mongo.getDB(uri.getDatabase());
DBCollection imagesCollection = db.getCollection("images");
DBCursor cursor = imagesCollection.find();
try {
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
       DBObject obj = cursor.next();
       Log.d("test", (String) obj.get("name"));
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Here's the error :

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting to connect after 10000 ms
at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:131)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getClusterDescription(DBTCPConnector.java:396)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getType(DBTCPConnector.java:569)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.isMongosConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:370)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.isMongosConnection(Mongo.java:645)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:454)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:546)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:571)
at com.leafstore.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:100)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Full log :

```
09-05 15:54:41.569: I/dalvikvm(10076): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean, referenced from method org.bson.types.ObjectId.<clinit>
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/dalvikvm(10076): VFY: unable to resolve static method 12702: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getRuntimeMXBean ()Ljava/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean;
09-05 15:54:41.569: D/dalvikvm(10076): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0071
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076): null
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076): java.net.SocketException
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at java.net.NetworkInterface.rethrowAsSocketException(NetworkInterface.java:224)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at java.net.NetworkInterface.collectIpv4Address(NetworkInterface.java:190)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at java.net.NetworkInterface.getByName(NetworkInterface.java:118)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfacesList(NetworkInterface.java:283)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(NetworkInterface.java:274)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<clinit>(ObjectId.java:548)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at com.mongodb.Bytes.<clinit>(Bytes.java:226)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at com.mongodb.Mongo.<clinit>(Mongo.java:76)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at com.leafstore.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:91)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     at java.net.NetworkInterface.collectIpv4Address(NetworkInterface.java:175)
09-05 15:54:41.569: W/org.bson.ObjectId(10076):     ... 21 more
09-05 15:54:41.589: I/dalvikvm(10076): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer, referenced from method com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer.<init>
09-05 15:54:41.589: W/dalvikvm(10076): VFY: unable to resolve static method 12701: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
09-05 15:54:41.589: D/dalvikvm(10076): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
09-05 15:54:41.589: E/dalvikvm(10076): Could not find class 'javax.management.ObjectName', referenced from method com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer.createObjectName
09-05 15:54:41.589: W/dalvikvm(10076): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1732 (Ljavax/management/ObjectName;) in Lcom/mongodb/util/management/jmx/JMXMBeanServer;
09-05 15:54:41.589: D/dalvikvm(10076): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
09-05 15:54:41.589: W/dalvikvm(10076): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/management/ObjectName;)
09-05 15:54:41.589: I/dalvikvm(10076): Could not find method javax.management.MBeanServer.isRegistered, referenced from method com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer.isRegistered
09-05 15:54:41.589: W/dalvikvm(10076): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 13063: Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;.isRegistered (Ljavax/management/ObjectName;)Z
09-05 15:54:41.589: D/dalvikvm(10076): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0006
09-05 15:54:41.589: W/dalvikvm(10076): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 1730 (Ljavax/management/MalformedObjectNameException;)
09-05 15:54:41.589: W/dalvikvm(10076): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0xb
09-05 15:54:41.589: W/dalvikvm(10076): VFY:  rejected Lcom/mongodb/util/management/jmx/JMXMBeanServer;.isRegistered (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
09-05 15:54:41.589: W/dalvikvm(10076): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x000b
09-05 15:54:41.589: W/dalvikvm(10076): VFY:  rejected Lcom/mongodb/util/management/jmx/JMXMBeanServer;.isRegistered (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
09-05 15:54:41.589: W/dalvikvm(10076): Verifier rejected class Lcom/mongodb/util/management/jmx/JMXMBeanServer;
09-05 15:54:51.598: W/System.err(10076): com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting to connect after 10000 ms
09-05 15:54:51.598: W/System.err(10076):    at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:131)
09-05 15:54:51.608: W/System.err(10076):    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getClusterDescription(DBTCPConnector.java:396)
09-05 15:54:51.608: W/System.err(10076):    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getType(DBTCPConnector.java:569)
09-05 15:54:51.608: W/System.err(10076):    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.isMongosConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:370)
09-05 15:54:51.608: W/System.err(10076):    at com.mongodb.Mongo.isMongosConnection(Mongo.java:645)
09-05 15:54:51.608: W/System.err(10076):    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:454)
09-05 15:54:51.608: W/System.err(10076):    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:546)
09-05 15:54:51.618: W/System.err(10076):    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:571)
09-05 15:54:51.618: W/System.err(10076):    at com.leafstore.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:100)
09-05 15:54:51.618: W/System.err(10076):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
09-05 15:54:51.618: W/System.err(10076):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
09-05 15:54:51.618: W/System.err(10076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
09-05 15:54:51.628: W/System.err(10076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
09-05 15:54:51.628: W/System.err(10076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
09-05 15:54:51.628: W/System.err(10076):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
09-05 15:54:51.628: W/System.err(10076):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 15:54:51.628: W/System.err(10076):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-05 15:54:51.628: W/System.err(10076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
09-05 15:54:51.638: W/System.err(10076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 15:54:51.638: W/System.err(10076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-05 15:54:51.638: W/System.err(10076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
09-05 15:54:51.638: W/System.err(10076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
09-05 15:54:51.648: W/System.err(10076):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 15:54:51.839: D/libEGL(10076): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
09-05 15:54:51.849: D/libEGL(10076): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
09-05 15:54:51.859: D/libEGL(10076): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
09-05 15:54:51.869: I/Adreno-EGL(10076): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
09-05 15:54:51.869: I/Adreno-EGL(10076): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
09-05 15:54:51.869: I/Adreno-EGL(10076): Build Date: 09/26/13 Thu
09-05 15:54:51.869: I/Adreno-EGL(10076): Local Branch: 
09-05 15:54:51.869: I/Adreno-EGL(10076): Remote Branch: 
09-05 15:54:51.869: I/Adreno-EGL(10076): Local Patches: 
09-05 15:54:51.869: I/Adreno-EGL(10076): Reconstruct Branch: 
09-05 15:54:52.129: D/OpenGLRenderer(10076): Enabling debug mode 0
09-05 15:54:52.159: D/OpenGLRenderer(10076): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x502
09-05 15:54:52.159: E/OpenGLRenderer(10076):   GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

Comment: Don't **ever** connect to a database directly from an un-secured client. Create a server with a REST API instead. Mobile phones don't talk to databases. Very bad practice.

Comment: Ok, should I do the same with my Java Swing app ?

Comment: What this means is **do not connect to MongoDB or any other database directly**. Use a web service with it's own authentication and service wrapping. Client's don't talk to databases directly over the web. It's just a fact you need to learn and accept.

Comment: I found in the REST API documentation :    Overview

MongoLab databases can be accessed by applications in two ways.

The first method - the one we strongly recommend - is to connect using one of the available MongoDB drivers. You do not need to use our API if you use the driver. In fact, using a driver provides better performance, better security, and more functionality.

The second method, documented in this article, is to connect via MongoLab’s RESTful API. Use this method only if you cannot connect using a MongoDB driver.